# How can I increase the perfomance of a real time video processing in browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-video, video-processing, video-capture

I use P5.js to capture a video from a webcam. In the draw function, which is responsible for redrawing the canvas, I add a new captured frame to the frame array and calculate the resulting frame, at that point in time using this pixel cube (frame array) and its 3D slice function.

```
sketch.draw = () => {

    sketch.loadPixels();

    this.capture.loadPixels();

    this.stack.push(this.capture.pixels);

    const pixelsStack = this.stack.array;

    for (let x = 0; x < this.w; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < this.h; y++) {
            const frameN = this.getFrameN(x, y, pixelsStack.length);
            set(
                sketch.pixels,
                this.w,
                4, x, y,
                this.getPixel(pixelsStack, x, y, frameN)
            )
        }
    }

    sketch.updatePixels();
}
```

On my MacBook Pro it works well when the resolution of the cube frame is 240x180x240. When you increase the resolution of the frame, it begins to freeze, on weaker computers the site crashes (even at a small resolution), on phones it does not work for more than three seconds if it starts to work at all.

I thought the bottleneck was p5.js, but then I decided to write my update loop using requestAnimationFrame, and output the resulting image to the canvas I created, but this only slowed down my application more than 5 times.

I tried to use webgl for this purpose, but I'm very unfamiliar with this technology. I tried to use textures to store frames, but it turned out it is too much data for textures. I also tried to use webgl functions from p5, but I only managed to change the way of rendering but not to increase the performance of the frame calculating (and the problem seems to me here).

How and with what technologies can I increase the frame calculation speed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to capture video via webcam, you can make use of the `MediaRecorder` API along with `getUserMedia`. No need for p5 or WebGL. Here is an article showing how to use these to set up a simple video recorder: https://dev.to/twilio/an-introduction-to-the-mediarecorder-api-2k8i